# Angular. Replace url parameter

Tags: angular

I have some component. In this component I can get url parameter, like this:

```
const campaignIdParam: number = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('campaignId');
```

Tell me how I can programmatically replace this `campaignId` in the address bar of the browser without reloading the page?

**Update**:
My url like this:

http://localhost:4200/#/company/2

Comment: angular have never `reload` page.

Comment: First, don't use snapshots of your routes. Second, read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#routing--navigation), which answezrs your needs. Third, consider providing a [mcve] of your issue so that we have a clear understanding of your need. Finally, you can redirect to the same route without reloading the page, or even reloading your component. Just try it, you'll see !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
this.location.replaceState(
           path, query, state
        );
```

From Angular docs:

```
/**
 * Changes the browsers URL to the normalized version of the given URL, and replaces
 * the top item on the platform's history stack.
 */
replaceState(path: string, query?: string, state?: any): void;
```

UPDATE:

More specifically you can use this code:

```
this.location.replaceState(
            this.router.createUrlTree(
                [tempUri],
                {queryParams: queryParamsObj}
            ).toString()
        );
```

Part of constructor for this code

```
constructor(private location: Location,
            private router: Router) {
}
```

Comment: I saw it. But I can't understand, how to replace the `campaignId`, for example with this url: http://localhost:4200/#/company/2. For example, 2 I want to replace with 3: http://localhost:4200/#/company/3

Comment: queryParams just add parameter via `?`, but I have url like this: http://localhost:4200/#/company/2

Comment: I update my answer - you can use `this.router.createUrlTree` for this, and update `tempUri` with : `/company/3`. You doens't use queryParams - this is parameter after `?`

Comment: It is unclear how to get `tempUri`, the witch component can be plugged into different other components, and the URLs there will be different, not just the `company`. I just wanted to replace the parameter by its name

Comment: @All_Safe in your case `tempUri` is `/company/3` or `/company/2` - it is a new URI, what you need in your browser url bar.